# Putting PHP code inside echo '' WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

This is in my `theme-function.php`. I'm printing this to the `index.php`. I am trying to make it dynamic,(changing it on my backend) but if I paste the 2nd code below the browser displays Server error 500.

1st code original code:

```
  <p class="welcome-block-text">Juan Aquino<br>
```

**2nd code: how to make like this**

```
 echo '<div class="row">

 if(get_option($shortname.'_custom_text_url','') != "") { 
        <p class="welcome-block-text">echo get_option($shortname.'_custom_text_url',''); <br>
 } else {
    <p class="welcome-block-text">Juan Aquiano<br>
 }
```

Comment: `echo` is not closed right? `echo '<div class="row">` where is delimiter?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Why not just echo the parts you actually want to echo?

Comment: your php code is incorrect not properly wrote according to php rules where is php opening closing tags ???

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Code Below refer it

```
echo '<div class="row">';
if(get_option($shortname.'_custom_text_url','') != "") { 
echo '<p class="welcome-block-text'.get_option($shortname.'_custom_text_url','').'<br>';
} else {
echo '<p class="welcome-block-text">Juan Aquiano<br>';
}
```

Comment: like this ? echo '<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-3"><div class="homepage-welcome-block-content-left"><a href="http://a-3.work/brunei/the-president/about-the-president/"><img alt="welcome-left-image" src="http://a-3.work/brunei/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/2.jpg" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1718"></a>
  <h3>President</h3> '.

  if(get_option($shortname.'_custom_text_url','') != "") { 
    . '        <p class="welcome-block-text"> '. echo get_option($shortname.'_psub_link','');.'<br>
'.      } else { .'
    <p class="welcome-block-text">Benigno S. Aquino III<br>
'.       }.'

Comment: Not, Sure What is your exception ? You need to do this in single echo statement ?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<div class="row">' . ((get_option($shortname . '_custom_text_url', '') != "") ? '<p class="welcome-block-text">' . get_option($shortname . '_custom_text_url', '') . '<br/>' : '<p class="welcome-block-text">Juan Aquiano<br>');
```

Don't forget to close `<p>` and `<div>`

Answer (score 0):

More simplified way to achieve this :

```
<?php 
if(get_option($shortname.'_custom_text_url','') != ""){
    $p_text = get_option($shortname.'_custom_text_url','').'<br> ';
} else{
    $p_text = 'Juan Aquiano<br> ';
}
echo '<div class="row"><p class="welcome-block-text">'.$p_text.'</p></div>';
?>
```